# D3JS or SNAPSVG drag and drop limited to loaded svg shape area

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, snap.svg

Anyone got any examples or pointers into using D3JS or SNAPSVG to snap a drag object to within the limits of a loaded SVG.

So for example if I wanted to drag a circle around an imported adobe illustrator svg filled shape that is far more complex than a rectangle (eg state of texas).

My estimated work flow is:

- Load map of usa.svg
- Load texas.svg overlay ontop of usa.svg
- User clicks anywhere in texas.svg and a cricle will appear which I can then drag but only within the limits of texas.svg paths.

Thanks

D

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the overall solution needed, you could possibly put a handler on one of the SVG elements, so that it only fires or is checked to see if its the right target.

So you select a state when you click it, and put the handler on the state rather than the circle (you can disable with pointer-events: none).

So you are 'dragging' the state, but moving the circle. We write our own custom handler for that.

This isn't a complete solution, it will need some further edge case testing, like dragging into a new state, or making not dragging/clicking outside the map. Its just an idea of one possible way to go, by using the event itself to limit its dragging.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/fhg1fah2/)

```
Snap.load( "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Blank_US_Map.svg", onSVGLoaded )

function onSVGLoaded( frag ) {
  s.append( frag );
  s.click( addCircle )
}

function addCircle(ev, x, y) {
  var t = Snap(ev.target)
  if(( t.data('dragEl') == undefined ) && ( dragging == false ) ) { // We only want one circle on a state
    var c = s.circle( x-10, y-10, 10)
             .attr({ style: 'pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.5' });  
    t.drag( dragMove, dragStart, dragStop ).data('dragEl', c)
  }
}

function dragStart( x, y, ev ) {
  this.data('targetState', ev.target.id );
}

function dragMove(dx,dy,x,y,ev) {
  if( ev.target.id != this.data('targetState')) { return }    // Check the event isn't coming from a different state
  this.data('dragEl').attr({ cx: x-10, cy: y-10 })
  dragging = true;
}

function dragStop() {  // prevent dragend causing new click
  setTimeout( function(){ dragging = false; }, 300);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the idea, I will look into it.